# how to join other table and count use python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'NET': ['P3V3_AUX', 'GND', 'P3V3_AUX', 'GND', 'P3V3_AUX', 'GND', 'P48V_2_ADMHS_VCC', 'P48V_2_ADMHS_AGND'],
    'Pin ref.new': ['C1.1', 'C1.2', 'C1102.1', 'C1102.2', 'C2.1', 'C2.2', 'PC17.1', 'PC17.2']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Pin ref.new'] = df['Pin ref.new'].str.split('.').str[0]
result = df.groupby(['Pin ref.new', 'NET']).size().reset_index(name='count')
result.rename(columns={'Pin ref.new': 'Pin ref.new', 'NET': 'NETA'}, inplace=True)
result['NETB'] = result['NETA'].shift(-1)
result = result.iloc[:-1]
print(df)
print(result)
```

and this is it's output,but is not i want
[image]

i want the output is be this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
# your code
df['Pin ref.new'] = df['Pin ref.new'].str.split('.').str[0]

# process
out = (df.assign(cc=df.groupby('Pin ref.new').cumcount())
       .pivot(index='Pin ref.new', columns='cc', values='NET')
       .rename(lambda x: 'NET' + chr(x + 65), axis=1)
       .assign(count=lambda x: x.count(axis=1))
       .sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.map({'count': 1}))
       .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

out:

```
  Pin ref.new  count              NETA               NETB
0          C1      2          P3V3_AUX                GND
1       C1102      2          P3V3_AUX                GND
2          C2      2          P3V3_AUX                GND
3        PC17      2  P48V_2_ADMHS_VCC  P48V_2_ADMHS_AGND
```

---

If all counts are only two, use the following code:

```
out = (df.groupby('Pin ref.new')['NET']
       .agg(count='count', NETA='first', NETB='last')
       .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: thanks~ i get it
but now i have a new question
because my data have other counts is more than 2, so if the count more than 2 ,
the columns will be more ,i have to drop other columns.

Comment: I solved that problem. Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

You can [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) (with help of [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html)), and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with the output of [`groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

# fix your reference
# extract is more efficient than split
df['Pin ref.new'] = df['Pin ref.new'].str.extract(r'(^[^.]+)', expand=False)

# set up grouper
g = df.groupby('Pin ref.new')

# pivot, rename columns, add the counts
out = (df.assign(col=g.cumcount())
         .pivot(index='Pin ref.new', columns='col', values='NET')
         .rename(columns=lambda x: f'NET{ascii_uppercase[x]}')
         .join(g.size().rename('count'))
         .reset_index()
      )
```

*NB. `ascii_uppercase` allows you to convert the column number to a letter, you're however limited to 26 columns, if you need more please clarify the logic.*

Output:

```
  Pin ref.new              NETA               NETB  count
0          C1          P3V3_AUX                GND      2
1       C1102          P3V3_AUX                GND      2
2          C2          P3V3_AUX                GND      2
3        PC17  P48V_2_ADMHS_VCC  P48V_2_ADMHS_AGND      2
```